# Is there any way to globally define user-agent and set of proxies for a program written on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seo

Pretty much the title. I`m wondering if it is possible to set a specific user-agent or even better, a couple of different user-agents? As well as define proxies that the program will use through the run.

The reason why I`m asking is because I need to check if the large amount of pages I need to check on indexing in Google.

Also, bit of an off-topic, but does anyone know where can I find some good free proxies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Been there. Done that. There is a way but the actual implementation depends on the library you are using for making http requests. The off-topic part is not a bit off-topic. It's totally off-topic on stack overflow.

Comment: You can try defining a function that accepts the a url or array of urls as arguments, then within the function you can now dictate the user agents and proxies to use.

Comment: I think I figured it out. In `requests.get` I can specify proxies and user-agents.